# linux pattern match program input

Tags: linux, pattern-matching, glob

I have multiple files with the same pattern: `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`, etc. I want to run a java program for each file, something like this:

```
java Main file[0-9]*.txt
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible to do what I want from the terminal? If not, I could change the program to read multiple args, but then again, I'd need to type all 100+ files manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the command

```
java Main file[0-9]*.txt
```

would pass all of the matching filenames `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, etc., in one command.  The OP requested "run a java program for **each** file", which implies that a series of commands is intended.  To do this (in bash or POSIX shell), one could do this:

```
for file in file[0-9]*.txt; do [ -f "$file" ] && java Main "$file"; done
```

Breaking it down:

- this makes a loop with `for file in file[0-9]*.txt` using the suggested pattern,
- it checks to ensure that the loop variable `file` has found a file rather than a wildcard expression which found *none*,
- runs the Java class `Main` for each corresponding file.